# Read a file and insert content to dictionaries

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a text file containing information on restaurants, what is required to is,to insert this information to several dictionaries.The attributes are name, rating, price range, cuisine type

Here's the content of txt

```
Georgie Porgie 
87% 
$$$ 
Canadian,Pub Food

Queen St. Cafe 
82% 
$ 
Malaysian,Thai
```

So far I've read the file and grabbed the contents to a list.

```
content = [];
with open(file) as f:
        content = f.readlines();
        content = [x.strip() for x in content];
```

Need to insert into three dictionaries
names_rating,price_names,cuisine_names how would I go about it?

Comment: You'll have to give a little more information. Specifically, someone would need to know the structure of the dictionaries in order to give a complete answer to the question.

Comment: Is your input exactly as you have given it in the example, or is it comma separated? In the former case, your main problem is finding where to split each row, to get the correct data in each dict.

Comment: Why not try until you get an error and can't figure it out?

Comment: The `line` variable you declare in the for loop already has the line you want, you should use it instead of using `f.readline()`

Comment: The code you've provided is probably not producing useful lists. `[x for x in some_string]` will produce a list of the characters in `some_string`, which is probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: Can you get the data in a CSV file? If that were the case you could just use `csv.DictReader()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Answer (score 2):

In general, to construct a list of dictionaries `lists_of_dicts` from a list of lists `list_of_lists`, where you're mapping the item at index `i` to the item at index `j`, you would use a dict comp like so:

```
list_of_dicts = {lst[i]: lst[j] for lst in list_of_lists}
```

You should be able to apply this to any arbitrary `list_of_lists` to solve your problem.

Comment: Where are `i` & `j` declared?

Comment: they're given in the setup, as is `list_of_lists`

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the example of file you gave, the elements are space separated.

So, your task would be to :

- Open the file
- Read each line
- Split the entries on spaces
- Save the entries in the dictionary

This would be done as follows:

```
names_rating = {}
price_names = {}
cuisine_names = {}
with open(file) as f:
    lines = []
    for line in f:
        content = f.readline().rstrip()
        if content != ''
            lines.append(content)
        if len(lines) > 4 :
            name = lines[0]
            rating = lines[1]
            price = lines[2]
            cuisine = lines[3].split(',')
            names_rating[name] = rating
            price_names[name] = price
            cuisine_name[name] = cuisine
            lines = []
```

In this, file is read line by line and the result is appended in a list `lines`. When the size of list exceeds 4, all the attributes are read into the list. Then they are processed to save data in dictionaries. Then the list is emptied for doing the process again.

Comment: All my file contents are in contents array.

Comment: @KumaranathFernando each line read from the file is saved as a `string` variable and not a `list`.  So the `content` variable cannot be a `list`. It is a `string`. Also trailing new line character `\n` is also read into the variable.  `rstrip()` function can be used on `string`s to remove unnecessary trailing characters. I have made corrections in the code according to this.

Comment: my bad I've made mistake on text content. Each attribute is not intended to separated by blank space but by new line

Comment: @KumaranathFernando In that case, you can easily read 4 lines one by one and save them in `names`, `rating`, `price`, `cuisine` variables and the rest remains the same

Answer (score 2):

Given your latest formatting spec for the text file:

```
Georgie Porgie 
87% 
$$$ 
Canadian,Pub Food

Queen St. Cafe 
82% 
$ 
Malaysian,Thai
```

if you can assume that:

- every restaurant entry will always be defined by four lines, each containing the fields you are after (read: dictionary entries)
- the fields will always appear in the same exact order
- each entry will always be separated by the next one via an empty line

then you could use the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and go for something like this:

```
import re

content = {}
filepath = 'restaurants_new.txt'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    fields = ['name', 'rating', 'price', 'cuisine']
    name = ''
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        modulo = i % 5
        raw = line.strip()
        if modulo == 0:
            name = raw
            content[name] = {}
        elif modulo < 4:
             content[name][fields[modulo]] = raw
        elif modulo == 4:
            # we gathered all the required info; reset
            name = ''

from pprint import pformat
print pformat(content)
```

EDIT:
the following solution was proposed after the formatting you posted originally, which looked like this:

```
Georgie Porgie 87% $$$ Canadian,Pub Food
Queen St. Cafe 82% $ Malaysian,Thai
```

I leave the original answer here, in case it is still useful for others.

As [JohanL mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743969/read-a-file-and-insert-content-to-dictionaries#comment76468948_44743969), the least trivial bit of the solution to your problem is the line formatting: depending whether you have commas or whitespaces as separators, or a combination of both, and considering that restaurants' names can contain un unkown number of words, it might become tricky to find how to split your row.

Here's a slightly different approach from the one suggested by @gaurav, using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (`re` module):

```
import re

content = {}
filepath = 'restaurants.txt'
dictmatch = r'([\s\S]+) ([0-9]{1,3}\%) (\$+) ([\s\S]+)'
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        raw = line.strip()
        match = re.match(dictmatch, raw)
        if not match:
            print 'no match found; line skipped: "%s"' % (raw, )
            continue
        name = match.group(1)
        if name in content:
            print 'duplicate entry found; line skipped: "%s"' % (raw, )
            continue
        content[name] = {
            "rating": match.group(2),
            "price": match.group(3),
            "cuisine": match.group(4) 
        }

from pprint import pformat
print pformat(content)
```

The advantage of this method, assuming you have no control on the source txt, is that you can tailor the regex pattern to match whatever "unoptimal" formatting it comes with.